# Detecting dictionary keys in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, loops, dictionary

I'm new to programming and am building a simple iOS app in Swift that allows users to add items to a list. I've got it working to add new items, see them in the list, order the list, see a detail view, etc. Each item includes a Name [String] and a Comment [String]. Name is input via UITextField, Comment is input via UITextView.

I've written a dictionary that associates a set of keys for example "cocktail" to a value for example "bar". Both key and value are Strings.

**I want to detect any dictionary keys entered into the Comment UITextView and return the value(s) from the dictionary.**

Curious how some may go about this...

Conceptually I think I need to:

- create a variable enteredCommentText to store what is entered in commentUITextView
- write a function that iterates over enteredCommentText to detect any keys (strings) in the dictionary
- return the value of each key for each key detected
- save those values as an array so I can do what I want with them

Bonus: Can I detect as users type, rather than after an event i.e. DidEndEditing or go to next field or hit Save, etc?

Any code suggestions on this is greatly appreciated. I've been playing with some dictionary syntax from Apple:

```
    var keywordDict: [String: String] = [
        "cocktail": "bar"
        ]

    //Look up a value, print the key
    if let wordValue = keywordDict["cocktail"] {
        print("The keyword is \(wordValue).")
    //Prints: "The keyword is bar."
    }

    let enteredCommentText = "Here is a sample of text. It contains a burger."

    //Detect text
    if enteredCommentText.containsString("burger") {
        print("found burger")
    //Prints: "found burger"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this with David's help and it's printing the values as I expect!

var myDict [String: String] [
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
]

for (key, value) in myDict {
            if place!.comment.rangeOfString(key) != nil {
                print(value)
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

You are right conceptually. Here is an example implementation that shows how to get the matching values for a given string - assuming you wanted `contains` instead of exact matching, which I gathered from your sample code.

```
let dict = ["Hi" : "there"]
let filteredString = "some text"
let matchingValues = dict.filter { $0.0.containsString(filteredString) }.map { $0.1 }
// matchingValues now contains all values of the dictionary where the key matched
```

If you are not familiar with `filter`/`map` syntax, here is a loop that achieves the same thing and is actually faster... but much less swifty! ;)

```
var matchingValues = [String]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    if key.containsString(filteredString) {
        matchingValues.append(value)
    }
}
```

If you want to get updates with every keystroke, you can use the following code:

```
class YourViewController {
    func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // other setup code...

        myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.textChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
    }
}
```

Note that you can also add the action through InterfaceBuilder by dragging from your text field to your class, and selecting 'Editing changed' as the event type.

Comment: David thank you for your answer! I've added your code and am able to return the dictionary value if the dictionary key matches the text in filteredString (exactly). However what I would like to do is return the value of each key for each key detected in the text. So if the text contains multiple keys, I want to return the value for each key ie multiple values.   I'll spend a bit of time with the code you provided -- thank you for your help!! -Sam

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is the code for what you need todo, when user type a word contained in the `dictionary` the we replace by the `value` on `dict`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfWrite: UITextField!

    let dict = ["cocktail":"bar"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tfWrite.delegate = self;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        let range2 = Range<String.CharacterView.Index>(start: textField.text!.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location),end: textField.text!.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location + range.length))
        let candidateString = textField.text?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range2, withString: string)
        //let bb = Range<String.CharacterView.Index>(start: range.location,end: range.location + range.length)

        var finalText = ""

        let components = candidateString?.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for word in components! {
            if(dict[word] != nil)
            {
                finalText += " " + dict[word]!;
            }else
            {
                finalText += " " + word;
            }
        }


        self.lbResult.text = finalText

        return true;
    }


}
```

I hope this helps you